# Spyder can't find Enthought packages

Tags: python, enthought, spyder

I am new to python and want to use the Spyder IDE with Enthought's academic distribution. I can get Spyder to run but it can't find the packages such as pandas that comes with the Enthought distribution. I can import pandas when I run python from the shell outside of Spyder. I am using Enthought EPD 7.3 64bit on OSX 10.7.5 and any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Spyder dev here: Which Spyder version are you running? Our native app or a version installed with pip or easy_install?

Comment: Native app 2.2.0 downloaded from the website a few days ago.

Comment: Do you have any other version of Python installed, except the one that came with the EPD?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can now give a proper answer.

Comment: I cannot run pygraphviz from inside Spyder (_ImportError: No module named pygraphviz_), although it has been easyinstalled to the same virtualenv (and runs from python in the terminal). Is this the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to import the packages that come with EDP you have to change your interpreter in

`Tools > Preferences > Console > Advanced Settings > Python executable`

to select the EPD interpreter, which should be located in

`/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/bin`

However, right now the app has a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1226) that prevents importing modules of different interpreters.

I'll try to fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I've got that set. Without the capability to use pandas from an IDE like Spyder, I'm headed back to R.

Comment: I'll report back when the bug is fixed. I'm sure that'll be the case at most by the end of the month, so don't get discouraged too fast! :)

Comment: (Enthoughter here) - Carlos, if the poster installed Spyder from source (pip or easy_install), within EPD, instead of using Spyder's native app, would Spyder's interpreter setting bug be bypassed, and pandas be usable as desired?

Comment: Yes @jonathan, there shouldn't be any problem (although I haven't tried it myself). In fact, for a long time we recommended our users to follow that path, but at the end we decided to create our own app because unfortunately EPD Free comes with PySide by default. PySide has always given us a lot of headaches, with weird crashes and segfaults, so we based our app on PyQt. Besides, for our next release I plan to include pandas, sympy and the scikits to increase its usability.

Comment: Good to know but the only reason to use Enthought is not wasting time with stuff like pip or easy_install. I'm excited to hear that pandas will be in the next release!

Comment: @ProbablePattern: We just released 2.2 Beta2 with my promised changes, including the fix to the cited bug and the addition of Pandas, etc. Enjoy!